# Adding nodes to Treeview control

Tags: c#, .net

I am playing around with the treeview control and have run into a simple problem. I would like to set it up as everything that is divisible by 10 as being the parent node, then the numbers underneath should be the child nodes, until it reaches another divisible number by 10 without a remainder. So my method looks like this and needs help! Thanks.

```
        private  void countDown(int num)
    {
        tv_NumList.Nodes.Add("topNode");
        while (num != 0)
        {
            if (num % 10 == 0)
            {
                tv_NumList.Nodes.Add(num.ToString());

                int counter = 9;
                while (counter != 0)
                {
                    tv_NumList.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(num.ToString());
                    counter--;
                }
                num--;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a [homework] problem.

Comment: At the very least you need to improve this `tv_NumList.Nodes[1]` as it is hardcoded to put the entries into the 2nd tree-node you created - which I think is in the wrong place too!

Comment: Hi Ray, that is where I want them. Anything that is divisible by 10 without a remainder should be in the Parent Node group[0], then the 9,8,7,6... should be in the child node group. Does that make a little sense?

Comment: Expand your question by showing a rough ASCII art of what you're looking for.

Comment: Parent node(to my understanding) is tv_NumList.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(num) and if a value of 30 is past it should hold 30,20,10.

Comment: What would you see if 15 were passed?  Would you be expecting 15->11 to be owned by the root or a magic introduction of 20?

Comment: Then the Child Node tv_NumList.Node[1].Nodes.Add(num) should hold the 29,28,27,26..ect until it hits 20 which would be parent node and would hold the 19,18,17,16..ect

Comment: I am only testing with numbers divisible by 10, I will throw more logic in later to handle other exceptions. For some reason, it wont add to child node.

Comment: @jpavlov: terminology might help here:  first level nodes (those belonging to the treeview.Nodes collection) are root nodes.  Child nodes are any node that has a parent node, thus root nodes are never child nodes.  Parent nodes have children, and may or may not have parents themselves.  Root nodes may be parent nodes, in fact, any node is capable of having children.

Comment: This will cause a stackoverflow exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is me, but I can't see what you're looking for... assuming you mean this (given 15)

```
root 
  |--15
  |--14
  |--13
  |--12
  |--11
 [+]-10


root 
  |--15
  |--14
  |--13
  |--12
  |--11
 [-]-10
     |-- 9
     |-- 8
     |-- 7
     |-- 6
     |-- 5
     |-- 4
     |-- 3
     |-- 2
     |-- 1
```

The following would (untested) give you this result.

```
// changed to take TV as a parameter.
private void countDown(TreeView tv, int num)
{
    // Create and remember your root node.
    var root = new TreeNode("root");
    tv.Nodes.Add(root);

    // This to remember the last 'grouping node' created.  Start with
    // the root node to deal with starting values not divisible by 10.
    TreeNode group = root;

    for ( int i=num; i>0; i--)
    {
        // Is it divisble by 10, if so, start a new group 
        if (num % 10 == 0)
        {
            group = new TreeNode(i.ToString());
            root.Nodes.Add(group);
        }
        else
        {  
            // Not divisible, so add to last group (or root if no 
            // group yet started) 
            group.Nodes.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close, but everything ends up the Parent node.

Comment: so 10 should be expandable and reveal 9,8,7,6,5 but they are all on the same level? Does that make sense?

Comment: Then a tree-view isn't the control you want if you're using WinForms (not clear but kind of implied by your example).  In WPF you could style the tree-view to show what you're after, but not from WinForms (or any other standard Tree widget).

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want the end result to look like:

```
-- ROOT NODE (Divisible by ten)
   +-- 30
   +-- 20
   +-- 10
-- ROOT NODE (everything else)
   +-- 29
   +-- 28
   +-- ...etc...
```

If that's the case then:

```
Int32 input = 30;
for (Int32 index = input; index == 0; index--) {
  treeview1.Nodes[0 == index % 10 ? 0 : 1].Nodes.Add(index.ToString());
}
```